# QGIS Action to update several fields

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, actions

I would like to update one ore more fields of my attribute table on demand (f.e. using a QGIS Action) with one simple click.

For now I have to open attribute table or the layer properties, start field calculator, choose the field I want to update, type or paste my expression and run it for every field I need to update.

I tried to use the model builder but I found no way, to simply update a field within the layer without creating a new layer.

Virtual Fields are not helping me in this way, because the recalculation will be time consuming (complex aggregate expression).

Comment: Is this for adding new fields to a layer or updating existing fields of a layer?

Comment: updating existing fields in a layer

Comment: So you have some preexisting fields in a layer and you need to run the field calculator for them individually, I'm sorry if I'm not understanding correctly but I don't see why virtual fields would not work. Once you set them up once then you don't have to get them to recalculate, they do it automatically. Recalculation won't be time consuming, it will not have any manual input at all. Again, apologies if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: The expression I want to use for updating the fields is a complex aggregate and is very time consuming.

Comment: Hello @MartinMap, have you find a solution to use action for attribute edition/update ?

Comment: If your expression is complex, have you tried writing it as a Function in python? And then using the Field Calculator to 'Update Selected Records only'. This way, you could optimize the expression in the code, and also only have it run on the records you want updated? Having it as code is also a nice progression to potentially deploying it as a 'button' on the GUI if you feel so inclined.

Comment: Yes, I could go this way! I solved it by using a Project-Model. You just have to run it, and everything is fine ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using virtual fields. In the field calculator check the `Create virtual field` button: [image]

When you add or edit a record or close and reopen the attribute table this will recaulcuate update on the fly.

For example if I create a virtual field for a polygon layer with the expression `$area` then when I create a new polygon it will automatically populate that field. If I change the size of the polygon then it will update.

You can also change the expression later by going to `Layer Properties > Fields` and edit the expression in there.

Comment: Virtual fields are nice but no solution in my case. I edit my question.